# faster testing of node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys Ive been programing in nodejs for a couple of months now. But testing of the code is a daunting task. im looking for a better way to test my code.

**My current setup:**

- server at digital ocean.
- PuTTY for running the app.
- Filezilla for uploading files to the server.
- Notepad++

**They way I test new code:**

- Close application at the server
- Upload new data through filezilla
- Reset server
- load web page to see effects of new code.

Although I can do all of these steps pretty fast , I would interested in tips to speed testing up ?

I read about nodemon and I think it would reduce on of the steps (resetting the server) ?

Frederik

Comment: Test your code _locally_ and with nodemon, only _deploy_ it to your server (optimally, with your CI that does a pull from your source control).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I'm sorry but what is CI ?

Comment: When you say testing, do you mean *developing*? If you don't have a local environment nothing you can try is going to be fast.

Comment: "When you say testing, do you mean developing?" - Yes that is what I mean. I never had nodejs instaled on my local machine but Ill try that :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run your application locally on your development machine, or another machine close to your development machine (e.g. a virtual machine (VM)). This will remove the need to transfer your application over the Internet each time you want to test. In order to do this, you just need to install NodeJS from the [website](https://nodejs.org/en/) or the package manager, and then you can run your application on your machine.

In addition, if your testing involves the repeated completion of certain steps after changes are made, then you might be interested in a testing framework such as [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), which will allow you to automate the testing process using more Javascript.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply its much appreciated. I see both you and  Benjamin Gruenbaum  suggested testing the code locally is the way to go?